# jQuery change a function on resize under 991px

Tags: jquery

I have a function on click in a class and I want to remove it on screen resize under 992px.
I mean to have  "#sp-menu" display:block; under 992px. 
My function is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 $(".showMenu").click(function () {
 var $that = $(this);
    $("#sp-menu").toggle("display", function() {
    $that.toggleClass("showMenu-on");
    });
 });
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS simply using media queries. Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3. It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

More on media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

or using jquery

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();

// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();


jQuery(function ($) 
{
    $(".showMenu").click(function () 
    {
        var $that = $(this);
        if($(document).width()<992)
        {
            $("#sp-menu").toggle("display", function() 
            {
                $that.toggleClass("showMenu-on");
            });
        }
    });
});



/****************  CSS NEW ********************/
.showMenu {
    color: #000;
    .fa {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }

}
```

Comment: I used (at)media with CSS, but you must refresh the page to read the (at)media and add display: block. But with your window line this is happening with jQuery without refreshing, thank you.

Comment: Hmmm. toggler is not working now..., when I click on showmenu is not working, so I added a !important to (at)media to show the menu. When I comment out your lines, it is working again

Comment: you asked for get document height < 992 px, as per your question. Rest conditions you can add in your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/geoplous/mzLa723k/23/    I think you have misunderstood something: I want the menu to be "display:block;" under 992px. So in the beggining, #sp-menu is "display:none;"  and under 992px will be display:block;

Comment: check the updated answer for CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/fbau9wqo/

Comment: can you please read again my edited comment above? thank you.